# Logic to find FIRST PASS RATE (Number of batch passed test the first time they came for testing?) for quality data in power query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz9lP.png)

I'm working on a quality set of data and trying to find the first pass rate. Attached picture shows a sample of lab testing data. Batch_id is a unique Id for every batch being produced and their respective result is in the Pass/fail column. If a batch fails the first time it comes to test then it has to be fixed and brought again for testing (thus you'll see same batch_id repeating) - this will go on untill that respective batch is passed. I'm trying to create a logic in power query to find the First pass rate of the batches - meaning, (total number of batches that passed the first time they came in)/(total batches). Can anyone guide me write a logic on the above problem, I'm new to power query and still learning my way through.

```
Date          Time        Batch_id      Pass/Fail
4/20/2023   10:00 AM        100         Yes
4/20/2023   11:00 AM        101         No
4/20/2023   11:15 AM        101         Yes
4/20/2023   11:35 AM        102         No
4/20/2023   11:55 AM        102         No
4/20/2023   12:30 PM        102         Yes
4/20/2023   12:50 PM        103         Yes
4/20/2023   1:30  PM        104         Yes
4/20/2023   1:45 PM         105         No
4/20/2023   1:55 PM         105         No
4/20/2023   2:15 PM         105         Yes
4/20/2023   2:35 PM         106         Yes
4/20/2023   2:55 PM         107         No
4/20/2023   3:15 PM         107         Yes
4/20/2023   3:35 PM         108         Yes
4/20/2023   3:45 PM         109         No
4/20/2023   4:30 PM         109         Yes
4/20/2023   4:50 PM         110         Yes
4/20/2023   5:30 PM         111         No
4/20/2023   5:55 PM         111         No
4/20/2023   6:30 PM         112         Yes
```

Comment: Edit your question to show data as text that can be copy/pasted.

Comment: Thank you Ron for the feedback, I've edited the question to include the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, reshape the data so the `Pass/Fail` columns returns *true* or *false* depending on whether or not the earliest test is classified as `Yes`

```
let

//next lines just read in your data from a pasted table
//and split it up into the separate columns
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ldNRC4IwEAfwryI+B263Tcu3InorfOglRGKUoFD0oN+fNkLptnmr4cvhz+PvcavrdK/HNpnPuX/O1U6Pt+7a3z9VpYchO+j+kTarOpUZMPOAMG84KxlLtsfpO26q6Vzawffc9Xz2p1eIc7XAF9oL7CHSXv3DoRQsqYI8mAZKhb2gvW2PvIx4qb648YqMb3/2dw529As8lAbs6JHPI96NU1BxhBenINsLL8464t1hbqg4Eq8C4qH2Eq+CWT36oii3PycvinKHSfPc6+5scvMG", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by WhiteSpace" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByWhitespace(QuoteStyle.None),
        {"Date","Time","AM/PM","Batch_id","Pass/Fail"}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Split Column by WhiteSpace",1),

//Create a Date/Time column from your data and remove the original
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Date/Time", each DateTime.FromText(Text.Combine({[Date],[Time],[#"AM/PM"]}," "))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date", "Time", "AM/PM"}),

//Group by Batch_id
//Then return "true" if the earliest item in the table is "true"
//   else return "false"
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Batch_id"}, {
        {"Passed on First Test", (t)=>
            Table.SelectRows(t, 
                each [#"Date/Time"] = List.Min(t[#"Date/Time"])){0}[#"Pass/Fail"]="Yes", type logical}       
       })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

There are probably many ways to display the results. Here's one

- Close and Apply
- Select the Card visual
- Add the following measures:

```
     Total Rows = COUNTROWS('Table')
     % of Total = DIVIDE([Total Rows],CALCULATE([Total Rows],ALL('Table'[Passed on First Test])))
```

Add the measure to the Card visual and format as percent, filtering or slicing for *true*

[image]

Here's a screen shot with both the Card visual and a slicer, so you select either:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It worked like a charm, I also had one more column to be grouped together and I included that in your group by code and it worked perfectly fine! Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On the power query editor you create a custom column name it "Date & Time" this is to merge date and time then change the format to "datetime"

```
[Date] & [Time]
```

Create a measure as below which would give you the first output if the result is pass on the report view

```
First_Attempt_Result = 

-- To get if passed in first attempt

Var yes = if (COUNTX('Table','Table'[Batch_id])=1,CALCULATE(MINX('Table','Table'[Date & Time]),distinct('Table'[Batch_id]),'Table'[Pass/Fail] = "Yes"),BLANK())

-- To get if failed in first attempt

Var no =CALCULATE(MINX('Table','Table'[Date & Time]),distinct('Table'[Batch_id]),'Table'[Pass/Fail] = "No")

Return

-- use yes to get the passed in first attempt and no if you need to get failed in the first attempt
yes
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the response. I tried this but it's calculating for every "Yes" in the Pass/Fail column. The idea was to calculate only when the sample passed the "First time" it came it. 
For example: batch_id 101 came in two times in total, first time it failed and it passed the second time - In this case the "Yes" in the second time should not be considered as it failed the first time.

Comment: What I initially  understood was that you wanted to capture the passed date hence the earlier code, I have edited the code with assumption that a passed batch_id will have only 1 test hence we can apply a countx to capture batch_id that is equal to 1 and filter by yes  condition which would only give batch_id of that have passed in the first attempt. Hope it solves your problem.